# Drag and Drop Game using AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var wordArray:Array = [mc_clipA, mc_clipB];
var imgArray:Array = [Aimg, Bimg];
var posArray:Array = [ {x:816.15, y:396.05}, {x:518.3, y:410.05}];

var ClipA:MovieClip;
var ClipB:MovieClip;

var startXpositionClipA:Number;
var startYpositionClipA:Number;
var startXpositionClipB:Number;
var startYpositionClipB:Number;

wordArray[0].buttonMode = true;
wordArray[1].buttonMode = true;

wordArray[0].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDownClipA);
wordArray[1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDownClipB);

//Mouse Down Function for ClipA
function item_onMouseDownClipA(event:MouseEvent):void {
    ClipA = MovieClip(event.currentTarget);
    startXpositionClipA = ClipA.x;
    startYpositionClipA = ClipA.y;
    addChild(ClipA); 
    ClipA.startDrag();
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_onMouseUpClipA);
    wordArray[0].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDownClipA);
    wordArray[1].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDownClipB);
}

//Mouse Up Function for ClipA
function stage_onMouseUpClipA(event:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_onMouseUpClipA);
    ClipA.stopDrag();
    var indexClipA:int = wordArray.indexOf(ClipClipA);
    var matchClipClipA:MovieClip = MovieClip(imageArray[indexClipA]);
    if(matchClipClipA.hitTestPoint(ClipA.x, ClipA.y, true)) {
        ClipA.x = positionArray[indexClipA].x;
        ClipA.y = positionArray[indexClipA].y;
        ClipA.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDownZip);
        ClipA.buttonMode = false;
        var tot=0; 
        tot=tot+10;
        score.text="You scored: " + tot +" Points ";
        var setTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,60);
        setTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,doTask);
        setTimer.start();
        function doTask(event:TimerEvent) {
        gotoAndStop(1,"Scene 2");
        setTimer.stop();
        }
    } 
    else
    {    
        ClipA.x = startXpositionClipA;
            ClipA.y = startYpositionClipA;
        wordArray[0].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDownClipA);
        wordArray[1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDownClipB);

    }
}

//Mouse Down Function for ClipB
function item_onMouseDownClipB(event:MouseEvent):void {
    ClipB = MovieClip(event.currentTarget);
    startXpositionClipB = ClipB.x;
    startYpositionClipB = ClipB.y;
    addChild(ClipB); 
    ClipB.startDrag();
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_onMouseUpClipB);
    wordArray[0].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDownClipA);
    wordArray[1].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDownClipB);

}

//Mouse Up Function for ClipB
function stage_onMouseUpClipB(event:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_onMouseUpClipB);
    ClipB.stopDrag();
    var indexClipB:int = wordArray.indexOf(ClipB);
    var matchClipClipB:MovieClip = MovieClip(imageArray[indexClipB]);
    if(matchClipClipB.hitTestPoint(ClipB.x, ClipB.y, true)) {
        ClipB.x = positionArray3[indexTie].x;
        ClipB.y = positionArray3[indexTie].y;
        ClipB.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDownClipB);
        ClipB.buttonMode = false;
        var tot=0; 
        tot=tot;
        score.text="You scored: " + tot +" Points ";
        var setTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,60);
        setTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,doTask);
        setTimer.start();
        function doTask(event:TimerEvent) {
        gotoAndStop(1,"Scene 2");
        setTimer.stop();
        }
    } 
    else
    {    
        ClipB.x = startXpositionClipB;
            ClipB.y = startYpositionClipB;
        wordArray[0].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDownClipA);
        wordArray[1].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDownClipB);
    }
}
```

This is regarding a drag n drop game. A particular object name will be displayed to the user then the user has to drag n drop the correct image to specified position and once the task is completed it will dynamically navigate to the next scene. For that i have used the timer class. I am getting this error in the scene 2 but in scene 1 the code runs perfectly.

The naming conventions are all correct but i still get the following error,

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at MethodInfo-1156()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: you do realize the timer is set to repeat 60 times?

Answer (score 0):

Your locally declared method "doTask" is removed right after the execution of the mouse listener. You should either create an anonymous inline listener

```
    var setTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,60);
    setTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, function(event:TimerEvent):void {
      gotoAndStop(1,"Scene 2");
      setTimer.stop();
    });
    setTimer.start();
```

Some like to do so but I am not a big fan of inline declaration. I would create a real method in my class as a listener.

```
private var setTimer:Timer;

function stage_onMouseUpClipB(event:MouseEvent):void {
  ...
  setTimer = new Timer(1000,60);
  setTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,doTask);
  ...
}

function doTask(event:TimerEvent):void {
  gotoAndStop(1,"Scene 2");
  setTimer.stop();
}
```